# how to know if SSIS is installed in my SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql server 2008 r2, I want to put my stored procedures in packages, i search the internet , i see that i have to install a data tool from microsoft for that. but this tool needs to be SSIS installed in SQL SERVER 2008 R2, how do i know if i have it ? thank u

#### this is my sql server 2008 r2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to SQL Server Configuration Manager (usually available in Start>Sql Server 2008 R2> Configuration Tools). Once launched, you have access to all available services. If Sql Server Integration Services 10.0 is there, you can right click it and start it, if it's not already launched. Otherwise, you will have to go to the installation center and add this service.

SSIS is not available on Sql Server editions. It's not available on Express for example. You can check your edition with [the following query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185.):

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Comment: in start ->sql server 2008 r2 , i have `import and export data 32-bit` and `import and export data 64-bit` and sql server managment studio

Comment: I should have asked first if you had the Express edition. If this is really the case, SSIS is not available and you will need to upgrade to another edition.

Comment: i dont know what version i have, how do i know ? bty i gave u the image in the qestion

Comment: I got `Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit)`, by the way i have visual studio 2012 if that might help.