# how do I install ssis on existing 2008 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Our current version of sql server left out ssis component how do I install it?  I have tried to go through visual studio and there is no ssis toolbox or anything dealing with ssis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the MSDN [install instructions for SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731(SQL.105).aspx)?

> Select Integration Services to install the Integration Services service and to run packages outside the design environment.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944008/how-to-know-if-ssis-is-installed-in-my-sql-server-2008-r2) provides a detailed way to find out if SSIS is installed and how to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Goto  `Control Panel\Programs and Features` select your setup. Please note you have to select where Size of Setup is zero. Click on Uninstall/Change. Follow on screen instructions. On installation type select add features to existing instance.... select your instance. On subsequent screens if you don't know much about configuration then keep all to default values.

[image]

[image]